# Why my sort rows function isn't recurring

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make x amount of rows be ordered by what they have in their first column. It has to be x amount of rows as the amount hat needs to be ordered can change.

The problem is is that the rows are not consecutive, and all the rows don't need to be ordered with all other rows. Some rows only need to be ordered amongst themselves.

I have managed to order the first section of rows encountered, but when trying to use a loop to carry on sorting the rest, my code doesn't fail, but does not sort the rest of the rows.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim startCond As Boolean
Dim stopCond As Boolean
Dim counter As Integer
Dim stopCount As Integer
stopCount = 1
startCond = False
stopCond = False
counter = 2
Dim neededRange As Range
Dim startIndex As Integer
Dim endIndex As Integer

For stopCount = 1 To 4
Do
    If InStr(1, Cells(counter, 2).Value, "Start", 1) = 0 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        startIndex = counter + 1
        startCond = True
    End If
Loop Until startCond = True

Do
    If InStr(1, Cells(counter, 2).Value, "End", 1) = 0 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        endIndex = counter - 1
        stopCond = True
    End If
Loop Until stopCond = True

Set neededRange = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(startIndex, 1), Sheet1.Cells(endIndex, 1))

Rows(startIndex & ":" & endIndex).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A" & startIndex), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A" & startIndex & ":CP" & endIndex)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Next stopCount

End Sub
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ascujl1lhk859bl/Eg%20for%20Excel.pdf

The Link above shows a picture of what i am trying to sort.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:
- the column index you should use in both your do loops should be 1 and not 2 - any time cells are merged, it is the cell as the leftmost / topmost position in the resulting range that will hold any value assigned to it
- you should re initialize both your StartCond & StopCond variables to False before each occurence of your loop

The code can be perfected, but that alone should allow to fix the problem - or feedback any further issue

```
Do
    If InStr(1, Cells(counter, 1).Value, "Start", 1) = 0 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        startIndex = counter + 1
        startCond = True
    End If
Loop Until startCond = True

startCond = False

Do
    If InStr(1, Cells(counter, 1).Value, "End", 1) = 0 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        endIndex = counter - 1
        stopCond = True
    End If
Loop Until stopCond = True

stopCond = False
```